# FFmpeg: Image sequence with ffv1 codec?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to output an image sequence in ffmpeg using the ffv1 codec?

If so, in what container, how would I reimport these back into ffmpeg?

- movie containers seem not possible for seq output
- i can force output -f image2 to any container, but import is not possible even with **-c:v ffv1** as an input option.

Encode of "intermediate.ffv1"

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 250 -i "/media/pool/vrender_input/movie.mov" -vframes 1 -c:v ffv1 -compression_level none -map 0:0 -an -f image2 -threads 0 "/media/scratch/intermediate.ffv1"
```

Decode of "intermediate.ffv1"

```
ffmpeg -y -c:v ffv1 -f image2 -i "/media/scratch/intermediate.ffv1" -c:v tiff -an -f image2 "/media/scratch/final.tif"
```

Error:

```
[image2 @ 0x2f85c80] Failed to open codec in av_find_stream_info 
 [image2 @ 0x2f85c80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: ffv1, none): unspecified size
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
 /media/scratch2/vrender_tmp/intermediate.ffv1: could not find codec parameters
 Input #0, image2, from '/media/scratch2/vrender_tmp/intermediate.ffv1':
 Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1, none, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[buffer @ 0x2f7ce20] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0x2f7ce20] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
[buffer @ 0x2f7ce20] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0x2f7ce20] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x2f6cfc0] Error applying options to the filter.
 Error opening filters!
```

Whats wrong?

Thank you!